# Transporting TRILL over Juniper QFX5100

Tags: juniper, tunnel, trill

I've got 2 Brocade VDX switches setup using VCS and want to add another 2 switches to this group, but when connected to each other over a Juniper QFX5100, they won't see each other.

The Brocade switches talk TRILL with each other to connect them in the virtual chassis.

I've tried setting up an extended-vlan-bridge but it doesn't seem to forward special frames. The incoming port on the switch receives some frames of ethertype ECP (0x88b7) and ethertype LLDP (0x88cc), but it's not forwarding anything to the other ports.

The configurations I've tried vary a lot. One of them is:

```
chassis {
    redundancy {
        graceful-switchover;
    }
}
interfaces {
    et-0/0/22 {
        flexible-vlan-tagging;
        native-vlan-id 45;
        encapsulation extended-vlan-bridge;
        ether-options {
            ethernet-switch-profile {
                tag-protocol-id 0x88a8;
            }
        }
        unit 45 {
            vlan-id-list 1-4094;
            input-vlan-map push;
            output-vlan-map pop;
        }
    }
    et-0/0/23 {
        flexible-vlan-tagging;
        native-vlan-id 45;
        encapsulation extended-vlan-bridge;
        ether-options {
            ethernet-switch-profile {
                tag-protocol-id 0x88a8;
            }
        }
        unit 45 {
            vlan-id-list 1-4094;
            input-vlan-map push;
            output-vlan-map pop;
        }
    }
}
protocols {
    layer2-control {
        nonstop-bridging;
    }
}
vlans {
    bro {
        interface et-0/0/23.45;
        interface et-0/0/22.45;
    }
}
```

A push in the right direction would be great. I'm interested in the solution on how to send encapsulated frames (the TRILL communication) to each other using intermediary switches.

Comment: I would first try configuring an l2circuit / CCC to see if a pseudo-wire link will allow the Brocade VCS to function as desired.  I know that's not your intended configuration, but it could provide some insight while troubleshooting.

Comment: @JeffWheeler I've tried to setup a pseudo-wire without luck. Do you have experience with this on the QFX?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The QFX5100 doesn't support TRILL (yet):

> NOTE: The hardware also supports FCoE and TRILL ether-types, but there
> is no software support for these packets. The software support will be
> available in a future release.

https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB28946&actp=METADATA

`extended-vlan-bridge` is something entirely different (VXLAN - tunneling a VLAN trunk over UDP).

If you need to cross the Juniper for TRILL the only chance is per pseudo-wire, as @jeffwheeler suggested.

You should also note that Brocade's VCS doesn't seem to be compatible with standard TRILL since it doesn't use IS-IS but Brocade's proprietary FSPF as its routing protocol.[[1]](https://blog.ipspace.net/2011/03/dont-lie-about-proprietary-protocols.html) You might need another Brocade switch or to rethink your protocol strategy.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The pseudo-wire didn't seem to be working for me. I thought the forwarding of such packages wouldn't be that much of a problem. I guess I will not be using VCS then.